# Real Analysis Proof 3

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose that,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

converges on $(-R,R)$ for some $R>0$. Assuming that $f(0)=1$ and $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in(-R,R)$. I need to find the coefficients $a_n$

So then when x=0,

$$f(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n0^n = 1$$

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$

But how do I use this to find the coefficiants $a_n?$

Comment: from your first identity we knows that $a_0=1$, from the second that $a_{n-1}=na_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$.

Comment: @Masacroso thanks I have edited that change in. Would you be able to help me out?

Comment: another hint: from the above comment we have the identity $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$, and we knows that $a_0=1$, then what is the value of $a_1$, and $a_2$ and... $a_n$?

Comment: @Masacroso so then would $a_1=\frac{a_{1-1}}{1}=\frac{a_0}{1}=1$ and $a_2=\frac{a_{2-1}}{2}=\frac{a_1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Continue a bit and you will see the pattern for $a_n$ clearly.

Comment: @Masacroso but didn't we say that $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, but the formula $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}n$ is a recurrence relation. You must find a closed formula for $a_n$ that doesnt depend of $a_{n-1}$. If you follow writing $a_3$, $a_4$, etc... you will see a simple pattern for this explicit expression for any $a_n$.

Comment: okay so then looking at the pattern is $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$?

Comment: Of course, it is. Moreover: you will learn soon that $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$ This is the reason why $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: @Masacroso okay so then to answer my question is the coefficiants $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much to add to the comment of @Masacroso...

$$f(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n0^n = a_0 = 1$$ Thus $a_0 = 1$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n} = f(x) = f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$$

This means that $a_n = (n+1)a_{n+1} \Leftrightarrow a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{n+1}$  for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Thus e.g. $a_1 = \frac{a_0}{1} = 1$.

You can derive a closed expression for the $n$th coefficient using this.

Comment: would that closed expression for the nth coefficient be $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}$?

Comment: I guess I should have said you can express $a_n$ explicitly as a function of $n$. If you feel lost, try to expand e.g. $a_3$:

$a_3 = \frac{a_2}{3} = \frac {\frac{a_1}{2}}{3} = \frac {\frac{\frac{a_0}{1}}{2}}{3}$.

Comment: okay so then looking at the pattern is $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$?

Comment: It is, if you can prove it. Else, it is not. :) Hint: use induction.

Comment: okay if that is the coefficient $a_n$ how do I prove that?

Comment: If you decide to use induction, then you have to show that it works for $a_0$, that is $a_0 = 1/0!$. Then assume that it is true for (or up to a given) $n \in \mathbb N$, that is $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$, and try to show that in this case $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: well we know that $a_0=1$ so then using our $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{0!}=1$ as $0!=1$ but then how do I prove $a_{n+1}$ for that third step of the induction process after we assumed step number 2 was true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55498/discussion-between-andrew-and-user905).